# I have xml without root element, how do i select value in the element

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have xml without root element, how do i select value in the element.

```
<id>ABC</id>
<code>true</code>
```

How can i select value from that element using XSLT.

Comment: how are you getting this xml? See if this can be modified at the source to inclue a root node.

Comment: If that is genuinely your input then it's not even remotely XML - I really hope it's a typo and the end tags are `</id>` and `</code>` respectively...

Comment: Sorry i written wrong xml

Comment: <id>ABC</id>
<code>true</code>

Answer (score 6):

> I have xml without root element

If it doesn't have a single root element then it is not a well-formed XML document and no XML parser will be able to parse it as one.  It is a well-formed *document fragment*, so depending what language or library you are using to parse the XML there may be a way to parse the fragment into something you can operate on.  Or if you have the fragment as a file on disk then you could create a wrapper document like this which "includes" the fragment as an external entity:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY frag SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<root>
  &frag;
</root>
```

This *is* now a well-formed XML document, and if you parse it you'll get a tree equivalent to

```
<root>
  <id>ABC</id>
  <code>true</code>
</root>
```

which an XSLT transformation can handle in the normal way.

Comment: That is not well formed.  Check your start and end tags!

Comment: While the method of using an entity is correct, it would only work if the XML in "fragment.xml" is actually a valid fragment. kstubs is correct, this has start id, end abc, start code, end true. Completely not valid and hence will not work.

Comment: @kstubs so it is, I copied it verbatim from the question and didn't check it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It seem your xml structure is wrong. Here the working xml - xls example : [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_value-of)

Comment: i know this structure is wrong but i want solution for that how can i get that value.

Answer (score 0):

The `#;$&@`symbols in value nodes sometimes break xml parsers. At least this happens in `*.resx` files and the error shown is as above.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @michael.hor257k the <root node is missing in xml> or <no xml root> redirects here from google. When xml is broken somewhere, even if the root node is not actually missing, a program (vs xml parsing extension) breaks on parse, printing root node not found exception.

Comment: But what does this have to do with the question???

Answer (score 0):

Given your later comment that fixed end-tag names, the sample XML is a well-formed XML fragment.

XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 cannot parse XML fragments but XSLT 3.0 can. In XSLT 3.0 you can use the [parse-xml-fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-xml-fragment) function as shown in the example below:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>  
  <xsl:variable name="xmlString" as="xs:string">
    <![CDATA[
    <id>ABC</id>
    <code>true</code>
    ]]>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:variable name="xmlFragment" as="document-node()" select="parse-xml-fragment($xmlString)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat($xmlFragment/id, ', ', $xmlFragment/code)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT, when invoked with the initial-template set to 'main', results in the following text:

```
ABC, true
```